# List Index Out of Range: Importing info from two lists into one conditionally

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, range

```
a = "alpha"
b = None
c = "charlie"
first_list = [a,b,c]

a_define = "a"
b_define = "b"
c_define = "c"
second_list = [a_define, b_define, c_define]

third_list = []

len_of_firstlist = len(first_list)

for item in range(len_of_firstlist+1):
    if first_list[item] is not None:
        first_list[item] = first_list[item] + second_list[item]
        third_list.append(first_list[item])

print third_list
```

This might seem a bit generic unfortunately, but I'm just so lost...
The code seems to work, but it keeps giving me an indexing error.

Comment: Of course it is, you are indexing to `range(len_of_firstlist + 1)`. Remove the `+1`.

Comment: Thank you both. Your answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are unclear about some of these points :

- `range(start=0,stop,step=1)` function starts from a default value 0 and stop when the value is *equal* to stop i.e. the `stop` value is *not* included. 
  For further information, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).
- Lists in Python are indexed from 0 (like arrays in C).

So if you want to traverse a string with length `n`, you need to define your range as `range(n)`.

If you want a more compact code, a few changes might be:

```
a = "alpha"
b = None
c = "charlie"
first_list = [a,b,c]

a_define = "a"
b_define = "b"
c_define = "c"
second_list = [a_define, b_define, c_define]

third_list = []

for item in xrange(len(first_list)):
    if first_list[item] is not None:
        first_list[item] += second_list[item]
        third_list.append(first_list[item])

print third_list
```

Comment: @HanaTheOtaku Mark this answer "useful" if you have accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

You are indexing from `0` through to `len(first_list)`, but the last index in `first_list` is `len(first_list) - 1`, because indexing starts at 0.

Remove the `+1` from your range:

```
for item in range(len_of_firstlist):
```

Rather than use `range()` you can use `enumerate()` to generate indices *and* access the value; use `zip()` to pair up the two lists:

```
for index, (first, second) in enumerate(zip(first_list, second_list)):
    if first is not None:
        first_list[index] = first + second
        third_list.append(first_list[index])
```